# mutt intermittently fails to send email

Tags: ubuntu, email, mutt, azure

In my azure ci/cd pipeline, I created a task to send an email using mutt. I use Ubuntu 20.04

There are no error messages. But the emails are sent intermittently. I created a trigger in the pipeline such that the , pipeline is executed after every hour. One day the email is sent 4-5 times and then it will completely stop. There are no failures. What could be the reason? I do not see any failures.

Here is the bash script which I use.

```
echo "line1"
sudo apt-get update
echo "line2"
sudo apt install snapd
echo "line3"
sudo snap install okular
echo "line4"
sudo apt install mailutils
echo "line5"
sudo apt install mutt

# Write your commands here
echo "line6"
chmod -R 777 deployment/
echo "line7"
npm install

# Generate PNG
echo "line8"
node test.js deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/log
echo "line9"
node test.js deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/report

# Generate PDF
echo "line10"
node pdf.js deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/log
echo "line11"
node pdf.js deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/report

echo "line12"
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils

echo "line13"
sudo chmod +x deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/report.html

# Generate Text files for log.html and report.html
echo "line14"
sudo pdftotext -layout deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/log.pdf deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/log.txt

echo "line15"
sudo pdftotext -layout deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/report.pdf deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/report.txt

echo "line16"
time=$(TZ="UTC-5:30" date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

echo "line17"
url=https://dev.azure.com/abcd/_build/results?buildId=$(Build.BuildId)

echo "line18"
echo -e "$url"

echo "line19"
echo -e "Please find attached reports generated at $time \n\nRegards\n\n\nLink to Azure DevOps Pipeline Build : $url\n\n\n\n
$(<deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/report.txt)\n\n\n $(<deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/log.txt)\n\n\n" | mutt -a deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/report.pdf deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/log.pdf deployment/$(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME)/report.html -s "Test Status - $(Agent.JobStatus) " -- abcd@someemail.com,xyz@someemail.com
```

Following is the result. There are no errors in the log. The bash script is executed till the end. However the email is not sent. What could be the reason?

```
2023-06-20T15:11:49.4712424Z ##[section]Starting: Email Task
2023-06-20T15:11:49.4717415Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-20T15:11:49.4717585Z Task         : Bash
2023-06-20T15:11:49.4717664Z Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
2023-06-20T15:11:49.4717798Z Version      : 3.224.0
2023-06-20T15:11:49.4717881Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-06-20T15:11:49.4717977Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
2023-06-20T15:11:49.4718127Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-20T15:11:49.6450599Z Generating script.
2023-06-20T15:11:49.6476721Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-06-20T15:11:49.6498333Z [command]/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/cb4761c6-dfb3-4b7e-bb0d-a20443cffe3f.sh
2023-06-20T15:11:49.6635746Z line1
2023-06-20T15:11:49.8275652Z Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
2023-06-20T15:11:49.8279835Z Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:49.8441670Z Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:49.8442637Z Get:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:49.8445561Z Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal InRelease
2023-06-20T15:11:49.8554966Z Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease [3611 B]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.1196942Z Get:7 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2635 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.1680335Z Get:8 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [443 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.1723101Z Get:9 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [16.9 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.1743036Z Get:10 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1983 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.2245107Z Get:11 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [278 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.2320441Z Get:12 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [636 B]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.2343149Z Get:13 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1074 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.2624647Z Get:14 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [256 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.2661611Z Get:15 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [25.1 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.4882055Z Get:16 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [2253 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.5513279Z Get:17 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [361 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.5519883Z Get:18 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [13.0 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.5559640Z Get:19 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [1873 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.5717746Z Get:20 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [263 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.5749598Z Get:21 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [640 B]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.5837791Z Get:22 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [849 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.5875965Z Get:23 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [175 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.5885098Z Get:24 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [18.5 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.7287899Z Get:25 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 Packages [207 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.7315522Z Get:26 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main arm64 Packages [41.8 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:50.7323685Z Get:27 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main armhf Packages [14.9 kB]
2023-06-20T15:11:57.9797879Z Fetched 13.1 MB in 2s (5512 kB/s)
2023-06-20T15:11:59.0724480Z Reading package lists...
2023-06-20T15:11:59.0941581Z line2
2023-06-20T15:11:59.1038589Z 
2023-06-20T15:11:59.1039461Z WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
2023-06-20T15:11:59.1039982Z 
2023-06-20T15:11:59.1607914Z Reading package lists...
2023-06-20T15:11:59.3714636Z Building dependency tree...
2023-06-20T15:11:59.3729820Z Reading state information...
2023-06-20T15:11:59.5680723Z snapd is already the newest version (2.58+20.04.1).
2023-06-20T15:11:59.5681103Z snapd set to manually installed.
2023-06-20T15:11:59.6607046Z 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 96 not upgraded.
2023-06-20T15:11:59.7393571Z line3
2023-06-20T15:12:50.3489816Z okular 23.04.1 from KDE** installed
2023-06-20T15:12:50.3519207Z line4
2023-06-20T15:12:50.3612753Z 
2023-06-20T15:12:50.3613547Z WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
2023-06-20T15:12:50.3613929Z 
2023-06-20T15:12:50.4169651Z Reading package lists...
2023-06-20T15:12:50.6099923Z Building dependency tree...
2023-06-20T15:12:50.6116130Z Reading state information...
2023-06-20T15:12:50.8118047Z The following additional packages will be installed:
2023-06-20T15:12:50.8120486Z   guile-2.2-libs libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 libmailutils6 libntlm0
2023-06-20T15:12:50.8121720Z   mailutils-common postfix
2023-06-20T15:12:50.8130743Z Suggested packages:
2023-06-20T15:12:50.8131417Z   mailutils-mh mailutils-doc procmail postfix-mysql postfix-pgsql postfix-ldap
2023-06-20T15:12:50.8188609Z   postfix-pcre postfix-lmdb postfix-sqlite sasl2-bin | dovecot-common
2023-06-20T15:12:50.8189200Z   resolvconf postfix-cdb postfix-doc
2023-06-20T15:12:50.8776221Z The following NEW packages will be installed:
2023-06-20T15:12:50.8783824Z   guile-2.2-libs libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 libmailutils6 libntlm0
2023-06-20T15:12:50.8786440Z   mailutils mailutils-common postfix
2023-06-20T15:12:50.9216041Z 0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 96 not upgraded.
2023-06-20T15:12:50.9914955Z Need to get 7457 kB of archives.
2023-06-20T15:12:50.9915760Z After this operation, 55.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
2023-06-20T15:12:50.9916984Z Get:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 guile-2.2-libs amd64 2.2.7+1-4 [4962 kB]
2023-06-20T15:12:51.1500633Z Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libntlm0 amd64 1.5-2ubuntu0.1 [14.7 kB]
2023-06-20T15:12:51.1626124Z Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgsasl7 amd64 1.8.1-1 [114 kB]
2023-06-20T15:12:51.1776616Z Get:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libkyotocabinet16v5 amd64 1.2.76-4.2build1 [318 kB]
2023-06-20T15:12:51.1955665Z Get:5 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 mailutils-common all 1:3.7-2.1 [272 kB]
2023-06-20T15:12:51.2115138Z Get:6 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libmailutils6 amd64 1:3.7-2.1 [437 kB]
2023-06-20T15:12:51.2313391Z Get:7 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 mailutils amd64 1:3.7-2.1 [138 kB]
2023-06-20T15:12:51.2465127Z Get:8 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 postfix amd64 3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2 [1201 kB]
2023-06-20T15:12:51.6395161Z Preconfiguring packages ...
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8090857Z Fetched 7457 kB in 0s (23.8 MB/s)
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8454109Z Selecting previously unselected package guile-2.2-libs:amd64.
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8679747Z (Reading database ... 
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8679994Z (Reading database ... 5%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8680185Z (Reading database ... 10%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8680579Z (Reading database ... 15%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8680766Z (Reading database ... 20%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8680951Z (Reading database ... 25%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8681136Z (Reading database ... 30%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8681318Z (Reading database ... 35%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8681506Z (Reading database ... 40%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8682054Z (Reading database ... 45%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8682308Z (Reading database ... 50%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.8998552Z (Reading database ... 55%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.9319561Z (Reading database ... 60%
2023-06-20T15:12:51.9566285Z (Reading database ... 65%
2023-06-20T15:12:52.0236488Z (Reading database ... 70%
2023-06-20T15:12:52.0690463Z (Reading database ... 75%
2023-06-20T15:12:52.1579882Z (Reading database ... 80%
2023-06-20T15:12:52.2258061Z (Reading database ... 85%
2023-06-20T15:12:52.2709387Z (Reading database ... 90%
2023-06-20T15:12:52.3561565Z (Reading database ... 95%
2023-06-20T15:12:52.3562246Z (Reading database ... 100%
2023-06-20T15:12:52.3563229Z (Reading database ... 255357 files and directories currently installed.)
2023-06-20T15:12:52.3709499Z Preparing to unpack .../0-guile-2.2-libs_2.2.7+1-4_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:12:52.3807807Z Unpacking guile-2.2-libs:amd64 (2.2.7+1-4) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:52.9327190Z Selecting previously unselected package libntlm0:amd64.
2023-06-20T15:12:52.9605697Z Preparing to unpack .../1-libntlm0_1.5-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:12:52.9618443Z Unpacking libntlm0:amd64 (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:52.9959042Z Selecting previously unselected package libgsasl7:amd64.
2023-06-20T15:12:53.0213639Z Preparing to unpack .../2-libgsasl7_1.8.1-1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.0224858Z Unpacking libgsasl7:amd64 (1.8.1-1) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.1036997Z Selecting previously unselected package libkyotocabinet16v5:amd64.
2023-06-20T15:12:53.1286300Z Preparing to unpack .../3-libkyotocabinet16v5_1.2.76-4.2build1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.1298474Z Unpacking libkyotocabinet16v5:amd64 (1.2.76-4.2build1) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.1837881Z Selecting previously unselected package mailutils-common.
2023-06-20T15:12:53.2093425Z Preparing to unpack .../4-mailutils-common_1%3a3.7-2.1_all.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.2103703Z Unpacking mailutils-common (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.2637685Z Selecting previously unselected package libmailutils6:amd64.
2023-06-20T15:12:53.2878169Z Preparing to unpack .../5-libmailutils6_1%3a3.7-2.1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.2884372Z Unpacking libmailutils6:amd64 (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.3596590Z Selecting previously unselected package mailutils.
2023-06-20T15:12:53.3833395Z Preparing to unpack .../6-mailutils_1%3a3.7-2.1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.3841291Z Unpacking mailutils (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.4429500Z Selecting previously unselected package postfix.
2023-06-20T15:12:53.4693024Z Preparing to unpack .../7-postfix_3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.7270994Z Unpacking postfix (3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.8867936Z Setting up libkyotocabinet16v5:amd64 (1.2.76-4.2build1) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.8896314Z Setting up libntlm0:amd64 (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.8929404Z Setting up mailutils-common (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:53.8958485Z Setting up postfix (3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:54.2425668Z Adding group `postfix' (GID 128) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:54.2856531Z Done.
2023-06-20T15:12:54.3246270Z Adding system user `postfix' (UID 119) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:54.3247099Z Adding new user `postfix' (UID 119) with group `postfix' ...
2023-06-20T15:12:54.4237742Z Not creating home directory `/var/spool/postfix'.
2023-06-20T15:12:54.4570576Z Creating /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf
2023-06-20T15:12:54.5073503Z Adding group `postdrop' (GID 129) ...
2023-06-20T15:12:54.5149377Z Done.
2023-06-20T15:12:56.3941249Z setting myhostname: fv-az196-197.fsmmeu0u0awerkbajh504c0zwb.fx.internal.cloudapp.net
2023-06-20T15:12:56.3987924Z setting alias maps
2023-06-20T15:12:56.4029516Z setting alias database
2023-06-20T15:12:56.4095984Z mailname is not a fully qualified domain name.  Not changing /etc/mailname.
2023-06-20T15:12:56.4099461Z setting destinations: $myhostname, fv-az196-197, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
2023-06-20T15:12:56.4147762Z setting relayhost: 
2023-06-20T15:12:56.4191268Z setting mynetworks: 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
2023-06-20T15:12:56.4249165Z setting mailbox_size_limit: 0
2023-06-20T15:12:56.4291538Z setting recipient_delimiter: +
2023-06-20T15:12:56.4334177Z setting inet_interfaces: all
2023-06-20T15:12:58.5460060Z setting inet_protocols: all
2023-06-20T15:12:58.5515267Z /etc/aliases does not exist, creating it.
2023-06-20T15:12:58.5594873Z WARNING: /etc/aliases exists, but does not have a root alias.
2023-06-20T15:12:58.5903775Z 
2023-06-20T15:12:58.5904471Z Postfix (main.cf) is now set up with a default configuration.  If you need to 
2023-06-20T15:12:58.5904893Z make changes, edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view 
2023-06-20T15:12:58.5905261Z Postfix configuration values, see postconf(1).
2023-06-20T15:12:58.5905460Z 
2023-06-20T15:12:58.5906098Z After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'systemctl reload postfix'.
2023-06-20T15:12:58.5906323Z 
2023-06-20T15:13:00.4041820Z Running newaliases
2023-06-20T15:13:00.7594534Z Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service → /lib/systemd/system/postfix.service.
2023-06-20T15:13:03.3854251Z Setting up guile-2.2-libs:amd64 (2.2.7+1-4) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:03.3894815Z Setting up libgsasl7:amd64 (1.8.1-1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:03.3917573Z Setting up libmailutils6:amd64 (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:03.3942763Z Setting up mailutils (1:3.7-2.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:03.4027681Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/frm.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/frm (frm) in auto mode
2023-06-20T15:13:03.4090726Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/from.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/from (from) in auto mode
2023-06-20T15:13:03.4153076Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/messages.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/messages (messages) in auto mode
2023-06-20T15:13:03.4216791Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/movemail.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/movemail (movemail) in auto mode
2023-06-20T15:13:03.4281548Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/readmsg.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/readmsg (readmsg) in auto mode
2023-06-20T15:13:03.4346554Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/dotlock.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/dotlock (dotlock) in auto mode
2023-06-20T15:13:03.4410529Z update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/mail.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/mailx (mailx) in auto mode
2023-06-20T15:13:03.4445897Z Processing triggers for rsyslog (8.2001.0-1ubuntu1.3) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:03.7649038Z Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-6ubuntu1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:03.9227577Z Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.21) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:04.2247068Z Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:10.2894545Z Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:17.5111474Z line5
2023-06-20T15:13:17.5205101Z 
2023-06-20T15:13:17.5211122Z WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
2023-06-20T15:13:17.5213285Z 
2023-06-20T15:13:17.5771995Z Reading package lists...
2023-06-20T15:13:17.8019977Z Building dependency tree...
2023-06-20T15:13:17.8034293Z Reading state information...
2023-06-20T15:13:18.0032333Z The following additional packages will be installed:
2023-06-20T15:13:18.0041948Z   libtokyocabinet9
2023-06-20T15:13:18.0053775Z Suggested packages:
2023-06-20T15:13:18.0054497Z   urlview aspell | ispell mixmaster
2023-06-20T15:13:18.0693984Z The following NEW packages will be installed:
2023-06-20T15:13:18.0698867Z   libtokyocabinet9 mutt
2023-06-20T15:13:18.1138628Z 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 96 not upgraded.
2023-06-20T15:13:18.1975911Z Need to get 1304 kB of archives.
2023-06-20T15:13:18.1976713Z After this operation, 5283 kB of additional disk space will be used.
2023-06-20T15:13:18.1977423Z Get:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libtokyocabinet9 amd64 1.4.48-12 [359 kB]
2023-06-20T15:13:18.2715774Z Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mutt amd64 1.13.2-1ubuntu0.5 [945 kB]
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7359754Z Fetched 1304 kB in 0s (8339 kB/s)
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7685262Z Selecting previously unselected package libtokyocabinet9:amd64.
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7768121Z (Reading database ... 
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7768720Z (Reading database ... 5%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7769345Z (Reading database ... 10%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7769597Z (Reading database ... 15%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7859498Z (Reading database ... 20%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7859737Z (Reading database ... 25%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7859926Z (Reading database ... 30%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7860117Z (Reading database ... 35%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7860304Z (Reading database ... 40%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7860493Z (Reading database ... 45%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7860677Z (Reading database ... 50%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7860861Z (Reading database ... 55%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7867323Z (Reading database ... 60%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.7898565Z (Reading database ... 65%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.8153813Z (Reading database ... 70%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.8194930Z (Reading database ... 75%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.8548980Z (Reading database ... 80%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.8790349Z (Reading database ... 85%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.8812616Z (Reading database ... 90%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.8995444Z (Reading database ... 95%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.8995723Z (Reading database ... 100%
2023-06-20T15:13:18.8995989Z (Reading database ... 256392 files and directories currently installed.)
2023-06-20T15:13:18.9110667Z Preparing to unpack .../libtokyocabinet9_1.4.48-12_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:13:18.9131085Z Unpacking libtokyocabinet9:amd64 (1.4.48-12) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:18.9763026Z Selecting previously unselected package mutt.
2023-06-20T15:13:19.0043457Z Preparing to unpack .../mutt_1.13.2-1ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:13:19.0235577Z Unpacking mutt (1.13.2-1ubuntu0.5) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:19.1731109Z Setting up libtokyocabinet9:amd64 (1.4.48-12) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:19.1767693Z Setting up mutt (1.13.2-1ubuntu0.5) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:19.1971217Z Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:23.7670896Z Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:23.9569011Z Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:27.5195016Z line6
2023-06-20T15:13:27.5208202Z line7
2023-06-20T15:13:28.4965559Z npm WARN old lockfile 
2023-06-20T15:13:28.4969768Z npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
2023-06-20T15:13:28.4970380Z npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
2023-06-20T15:13:28.4971897Z npm WARN old lockfile 
2023-06-20T15:13:28.4972591Z npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
2023-06-20T15:13:28.4972981Z npm WARN old lockfile 
2023-06-20T15:13:37.2127153Z npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
2023-06-20T15:13:37.4221955Z npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
2023-06-20T15:13:37.5953457Z npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
2023-06-20T15:13:37.6109641Z npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
2023-06-20T15:13:38.6854081Z npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
2023-06-20T15:13:39.6458027Z npm WARN deprecated puppeteer@13.1.1: < 19.4.0 is no longer supported
2023-06-20T15:13:48.3779320Z 
2023-06-20T15:13:48.3780326Z added 381 packages, and audited 382 packages in 20s
2023-06-20T15:13:48.3784171Z 
2023-06-20T15:13:48.3784702Z 14 packages are looking for funding
2023-06-20T15:13:48.3785398Z   run `npm fund` for details
2023-06-20T15:13:48.3947779Z 
2023-06-20T15:13:48.3948610Z 10 high severity vulnerabilities
2023-06-20T15:13:48.4004039Z 
2023-06-20T15:13:48.4004685Z To address issues that do not require attention, run:
2023-06-20T15:13:48.4004899Z   npm audit fix
2023-06-20T15:13:48.4004985Z 
2023-06-20T15:13:48.4005191Z To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
2023-06-20T15:13:48.4005669Z   npm audit fix --force
2023-06-20T15:13:48.4005746Z 
2023-06-20T15:13:48.4006035Z Run `npm audit` for details.
2023-06-20T15:13:48.4176672Z line8
2023-06-20T15:13:50.0389569Z line9
2023-06-20T15:13:51.4688252Z line10
2023-06-20T15:13:54.2907376Z line11
2023-06-20T15:13:55.8056999Z line12
2023-06-20T15:13:55.8711063Z Reading package lists...
2023-06-20T15:13:56.0747557Z Building dependency tree...
2023-06-20T15:13:56.0761568Z Reading state information...
2023-06-20T15:13:56.2582802Z The following additional packages will be installed:
2023-06-20T15:13:56.2585150Z   libopenjp2-7 libpoppler97 poppler-data
2023-06-20T15:13:56.2591901Z Suggested packages:
2023-06-20T15:13:56.2592624Z   ghostscript fonts-japanese-mincho | fonts-ipafont-mincho
2023-06-20T15:13:56.2642867Z   fonts-japanese-gothic | fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-arphic-ukai
2023-06-20T15:13:56.2643259Z   fonts-arphic-uming fonts-nanum
2023-06-20T15:13:56.2769480Z The following NEW packages will be installed:
2023-06-20T15:13:56.2774131Z   libopenjp2-7 libpoppler97 poppler-data poppler-utils
2023-06-20T15:13:56.3281358Z 0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 96 not upgraded.
2023-06-20T15:13:56.3282280Z Need to get 2706 kB of archives.
2023-06-20T15:13:56.3282564Z After this operation, 17.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
2023-06-20T15:13:56.3283287Z Get:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 poppler-data all 0.4.9-2 [1475 kB]
2023-06-20T15:13:56.4160764Z Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libopenjp2-7 amd64 2.3.1-1ubuntu4.20.04.1 [141 kB]
2023-06-20T15:13:56.4296170Z Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpoppler97 amd64 0.86.1-0ubuntu1.1 [916 kB]
2023-06-20T15:13:56.4586503Z Get:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 poppler-utils amd64 0.86.1-0ubuntu1.1 [174 kB]
2023-06-20T15:13:56.8801891Z Fetched 2706 kB in 0s (15.2 MB/s)
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9159334Z Selecting previously unselected package poppler-data.
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9192269Z (Reading database ... 
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9192813Z (Reading database ... 5%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9194789Z (Reading database ... 10%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9195219Z (Reading database ... 15%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9195669Z (Reading database ... 20%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9197863Z (Reading database ... 25%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9198289Z (Reading database ... 30%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9198620Z (Reading database ... 35%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9198971Z (Reading database ... 40%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9199398Z (Reading database ... 45%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9250635Z (Reading database ... 50%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9250842Z (Reading database ... 55%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9271670Z (Reading database ... 60%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9295964Z (Reading database ... 65%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9554349Z (Reading database ... 70%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9591217Z (Reading database ... 75%
2023-06-20T15:13:56.9952893Z (Reading database ... 80%
2023-06-20T15:13:57.0201611Z (Reading database ... 85%
2023-06-20T15:13:57.0224531Z (Reading database ... 90%
2023-06-20T15:13:57.0410970Z (Reading database ... 95%
2023-06-20T15:13:57.0411310Z (Reading database ... 100%
2023-06-20T15:13:57.0411591Z (Reading database ... 256475 files and directories currently installed.)
2023-06-20T15:13:57.0528231Z Preparing to unpack .../poppler-data_0.4.9-2_all.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.0538215Z Unpacking poppler-data (0.4.9-2) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.3088792Z Selecting previously unselected package libopenjp2-7:amd64.
2023-06-20T15:13:57.3366883Z Preparing to unpack .../libopenjp2-7_2.3.1-1ubuntu4.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.3387935Z Unpacking libopenjp2-7:amd64 (2.3.1-1ubuntu4.20.04.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.3758498Z Selecting previously unselected package libpoppler97:amd64.
2023-06-20T15:13:57.4030860Z Preparing to unpack .../libpoppler97_0.86.1-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.4037470Z Unpacking libpoppler97:amd64 (0.86.1-0ubuntu1.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.5156839Z Selecting previously unselected package poppler-utils.
2023-06-20T15:13:57.5384897Z Preparing to unpack .../poppler-utils_0.86.1-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.5397092Z Unpacking poppler-utils (0.86.1-0ubuntu1.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.6144892Z Setting up poppler-data (0.4.9-2) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.6235396Z Setting up libopenjp2-7:amd64 (2.3.1-1ubuntu4.20.04.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.6260931Z Setting up libpoppler97:amd64 (0.86.1-0ubuntu1.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.6293948Z Setting up poppler-utils (0.86.1-0ubuntu1.1) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.6343828Z Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
2023-06-20T15:13:57.6536725Z Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
2023-06-20T15:14:02.1000888Z Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.13.1-2ubuntu3) ...
2023-06-20T15:14:05.5988453Z line13
2023-06-20T15:14:05.6059026Z line14
2023-06-20T15:14:05.6347491Z line15
2023-06-20T15:14:05.6505484Z line16
2023-06-20T15:14:05.6522805Z line17
2023-06-20T15:14:05.6523175Z line18
2023-06-20T15:14:05.6523750Z https://dev.azure.com/abcd/_build/results?buildId=5246926
2023-06-20T15:14:05.6524062Z line19
2023-06-20T15:14:05.8118098Z ##[section]Finishing: Email Task
```